# No Exception thrown from a second method, why?

Tags: java, exception

The sample code is:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListOfNumbers{
    private static int Size=10;               // this is a class variable- as there should be only 1 instance of the class.
    private List<Integer> list;

    public ListOfNumbers(){
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Size);        // an arraylist of size-10.
    System.out.println("Populating the list");
    for(int i =0; i<Size; i++)
    {
    list.add(new Integer(i));   // is similar to using list.add(i); /* this involves auto-boxing*/
    }
    System.out.println("List populated");
    }

    public void writeList(File file){
    FileWriter out = null;
    try{
    out = new FileWriter(file);
    System.out.println("Start Writing to the File" + " " +file);
    for(int i =0; i < Size; i++)
    {
    out.write("Value at" + i + "is:" +" " + (list.get(i)).intValue());  //is similar to writing list.get(i) /*this will return Integer, because of AB it will treated int*/
    out.write("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Contents written to the file");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex){
    fnfex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioex){
    ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
    if(out != null)
    {
        try{
            out.close();
           }

        catch(IOException ioex)
        {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else
        System.out.println("Stream not open");

    }
    }

    public void readList(File file)
    {
    String pointer = null;
    String [] value = null;
    RandomAccessFile  input = null;
    System.out.println("Trying to read from file:" + " " + file);
    try{
    System.out.println("In the try block");
    input= new RandomAccessFile(file,"r");  //should throw exception
    System.out.println("Created a reference to the file"+ file);
    while((pointer = input.readLine()) !=null)  //should throw exception
    {
    System.out.println("In the while block");
    System.out.println(pointer);
    value = pointer.split(": ");
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(value[1]));
    }

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfex)
    {
    fnfex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioex)
    {
    ioex.getMessage();
    }

    } 

    public void displayList(){
    System.out.println("Displaying List elements");
//  list.size();
    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i));    
    }
    }
    public static void main(String [] par)
    {
        ListOfNumbers obj = new ListOfNumbers();
        File file = new File("Output.txt");
        obj.writeList(file);
        obj.readList(file);
        obj.displayList();

    }

}
```

Results:-

```
Populating the list
List populated
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Output.txt (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at ListOfNumbers.writeList(ListOfNumbers.java:22)
    at ListOfNumbers.main(ListOfNumbers.java:97)
Stream not open
Trying to read from file: Output.txt
In the try block
Created a reference to the fileOutput.txt
Displaying List elements
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I have changed permissions on `Output.txt` so that I get the exception. My question is why isn't readList () method not throwing exceptions when we try to access the file i.e assign a reference to input and when we try to use it in while loop.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file? Reading it doesn't require much

Comment: How did you change the permissions? Is the file now r, rw or neither?

Comment: You **only** have `ioex.getMessage();` in the `IOException` catch block. That does nothing! Either *print* the message or (better) print the stack trace as you do with the FNF Exception.

Comment: file permissions are 664 and the owner of the file is root and group owner is also root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output's according to various file permissions:-

1)    -rw-rw---- 1 root   root      0 Nov 15 17:23 Output.txt

```
    buffer@ankit:/home/mount/Data/JAVA/practice/src$ java ListOfNumbers 
Populating the list
List populated
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Output.txt (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at ListOfNumbers.writeList(ListOfNumbers.java:22)
    at ListOfNumbers.main(ListOfNumbers.java:97)
Stream not open
Trying to read from file: Output.txt
In the try block
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Output.txt (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at ListOfNumbers.readList(ListOfNumbers.java:64)
    at ListOfNumbers.main(ListOfNumbers.java:98)
Displaying List elements
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

2) -rw-rw---- 1 buffer buffer    0 Nov 15 17:23 Output.txt

```
buffer@ankit:/home/mount/Data/JAVA/practice/src$ java ListOfNumbers 
Populating the list
List populated
Start Writing to the File Output.txt
Contents written to the file
Trying to read from file: Output.txt
In the try block
Created a reference to the fileOutput.txt
In the while block
Value at0is: 0
In the while block
Value at1is: 1
In the while block
Value at2is: 2
In the while block
Value at3is: 3
In the while block
Value at4is: 4
In the while block
Value at5is: 5
In the while block
Value at6is: 6
In the while block
Value at7is: 7
In the while block
Value at8is: 8
In the while block
Value at9is: 9
Displaying List elements
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

3) -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 150 Nov 16 05:16 Output.txt

```
buffer@ankit:/home/mount/Data/JAVA/practice/src$ java ListOfNumbers 
Populating the list
List populated
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Output.txt (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at ListOfNumbers.writeList(ListOfNumbers.java:22)
    at ListOfNumbers.main(ListOfNumbers.java:97)
Stream not open
Trying to read from file: Output.txt
In the try block
Created a reference to the fileOutput.txt
In the while block
Value at0is: 0
In the while block
Value at1is: 1
In the while block
Value at2is: 2
In the while block
Value at3is: 3
In the while block
Value at4is: 4
In the while block
Value at5is: 5
In the while block
Value at6is: 6
In the while block
Value at7is: 7
In the while block
Value at8is: 8
In the while block
Value at9is: 9
Displaying List elements
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```